# Calculate timespan metric between two service bus topics from two Azure function apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I've two service bus triggers, each one created/defined in separate two Azure function app projects. Ideally the flow is when I receive a message to the service bus topic in 1st Azure function app it'll process info and transfer that message to the 2nd service bus topic in 2nd Azure function app and again it'll process that message and finally deliver it to the end user in an email/sms format.

Currently there are processing time metrics available/calculated in each of the function apps (i.e. 1 and 2), but I'm looking to sum up the processing time from both the function apps and capture the metric.

Will it be possible to sum up the processing time from two Azure function apps and capture that metric in the 2nd Azure function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to add some sort of metadata to the body of the Service Bus Message, that keeps track of the metrics. I'll provide two answers depending on which answer you're looking for:

- **Case 1:** timeInProcess1 + timeInProcess2
- **Case 2:** timeInProcess1 + timeInbetween + timeInProcess2

### Case 1

Add the processing time as metadata in the body of your Service Bus Messages. E.g. if you are using a body with json data:

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "totalProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": 0,
    ..
  },
  ..
}
```

```cs
// Parse the message body into a DTO mirroring the message body
receivedMessageBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageBody>(receivedMessage.Body.ToString());

// Do any neccessary checks to validate the data
// ..

// Use message received from the first function app and sum it with the current (second function app) processing time
var totalProcessingTimeInMs = receivedMessageBody.Metadata.TotalProcessingTimeInMilliseconds + currentProcessingTimeInMs;

// Create your email/sms and sending along totalProcessingTimeInMs
// ...
```

### Case 2

Instead of using the processing time metric that your apps calculate, save the start DateTime/DateTimeOffest of the first process in the metadata. Then, when the second process is finished, save the end DateTime/DateTimeOffset and calculate the difference:

```cs
var endOfProcess2 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var totalProcessingTimeInMs = (endOfProcess2 - receivedMessageBody.Metadata.StartOfProcess1).TotalMilliseconds;


// Create your email/sms and sending along totalProcessingTimeInMs
// ...
```